# Android: App has stopped working issue

Tags: android, android-webview, apk

i have added a side options menu in my app with back, refresh, forward & about options, but whenever i click on any of those buttons my app stop working, please help me.

If possible please highlight the part of the code which is wrong..

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView myWebView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
    // browser app does.
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    webview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    final Activity activity = this;
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //This will load the webpage that we want to see
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxx.com");



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // Add menu items, second value is the id, use this in the onCreateOptionsMenu
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Back");
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Refresh");
    menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Forward");
    menu.add(0, 4, 0, "About");
    return true; // End of menu configuration
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){ // Called when you tap a menu item

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 1: //If the ID equals 1, go back
            if (myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
                }
        case 2 : //If the ID equals 2, refresh
            myWebView.reload();
            return true;
        case 3: //If the ID equals 3, go forward
            if (myWebView.canGoForward()){
            myWebView.goForward();
            return true;
            }
        case 4: //aha showing about us
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/about.php");
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { // Enables browsing to previous pages with the hardware back button
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }   // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Here is the log:

```
08-04 12:38:25.319        37-37/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-04 12:38:28.687    3589-3589/com.example D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-04 12:38:28.687    3589-3589/com.example W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-04 12:38:28.778    3589-3589/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:125)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 12:38:28.817      322-542/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.example/.MainActivity
08-04 12:38:28.837      322-542/system_process W/WindowManager: Failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21035
08-04 12:38:29.287       37-162/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-04 12:38:29.425      322-337/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{411a3cd0 u0 com.example/.MainActivity}
08-04 12:38:29.747      708-723/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: Received deviceId from Email app: null
08-04 12:38:29.747      708-723/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
08-04 12:38:30.047      457-457/com.android.launcher I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 12:38:30.337        37-37/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-04 12:38:34.848      708-724/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! EAS     ExchangeService, onCreate
08-04 12:38:34.848      708-708/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
08-04 12:38:34.858      322-560/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-04 12:38:34.858      708-898/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! Email application not found; stopping self
08-04 12:38:34.880      322-669/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-04 12:38:34.887      708-708/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
08-04 12:38:34.918      708-708/com.android.exchange E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4ceb0 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4ceb0 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 12:38:35.021      708-708/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4ceb0 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 12:38:35.021      322-333/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@411d8540
08-04 12:38:35.047      708-708/com.android.exchange E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0338 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0338 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 12:38:35.047      708-708/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0338 that was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 12:38:35.068      322-474/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@411d82a8
08-04 12:38:35.118      708-711/com.android.exchange D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 464K, 20% free 2503K/3112K, paused 80ms+7ms, total 189ms
08-04 12:38:42.870      322-337/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{411a3cd0 u0 com.example/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: pls post the stack trace.

Comment: No don't post the stack trace. _Read_ the stack trace. Check your logcat where you'll find the exception that caused the crash, along with the line number at which the exception occured. After doing this you might not need us anymore. Look for the informative `Caused by` line.

Comment: i have added the log,as i cant understand the issue in it.. please help :( @ Keyser

Comment: @itseasy21 where have you initialized `myWebview`? i see only this  `WebView webview = new WebView(this)`

Comment: yes i forgot to initialize it thanks.. Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `myWebView`.

I guess you should add the following code in your `onCreate` method:

> myWebView = webview;

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, yes i forgot to initialize it :P